# How to check a tensor is a single value in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to check if a tensor is just a number. Is there any way to make such check nicer than `shape == ()` ?

```
tensor_number = tf.constant(1)
tensor_not_number = tf.constant([1])

print(tensor_number.shape == ())
print(tensor_not_number.shape == ())

>> True
>> False
```

Answer (score 0):

A scalar tensor has zero rank. We can use `tf.rank` to check whether a tensor is a scalar.

```
a=tf.constant(np.random.rand(3,3,3))
b=tf.constant(np.random.rand())
c=tf.constant(np.random.rand(1))
tf.print(tf.rank(a))
tf.print(tf.rank(b))
tf.print(tf.rank(c))
if tf.rank(b) == 0:
  tf.print('b is a scalar')
'''
3
0
1
b is a scalar
'''
```